# Is it possible to check if a message doesn't contain "ew" it deletes the message?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm making a pretty lame server where the only purpose is to say "ew" in chat.

Is it possible to check if the message contains anything other than "ew", it automatically deletes the message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
if(!message.content.includes("ew")){
   message.delete();
}
```

Or you could do the old fashion way:

```
if(message.content.indexOf("ew") === -1){
   message.delete(); 
}
```